# retrofit protobuf-lite converter in Java

Tags: retrofit, protocol-buffers, retrofit2

Does retrofit support protobuf-lite converter in Java? In my case, I have to use both retrofit and protobuf-lite, but if I add dependencies like this:

```
compile "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.0"
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-protobuf:2.3.0'
```

then protobuf 3.0.0 will also be download by retrofit, this makes me get

```
com/a/a/a$a.class == protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar:com/google/protobuf/AbstractMessageLite$Builder.class
```

error. Is there any solutions to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Works for me using 2.4.0 and specifying `transitive = false` so that gradle doesn't pull in protobuf-java.

`implementation ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-protobuf:2.4.0') {
        transitive = false;
    }`